# ant build script issue

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have 2 ant build scripts named "build" and "tarne"

Build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="build" default="zip">

    <property name="project.name" value="projectName"/>
    <property name="version" value="default_version_value"/>


    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/build/ant-contrib.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>  

    <var name="version2" value="default_version_value"/>


    <property name="tmp" value="tmp"/>  
    <property name="build.dir" location="${tmp}/component/${project.name}"/>
    <property name="java.classes" location="${tmp}/component/${project.name}/classes"/>
    <property name="weblayout.dir" location="${tmp}/weblayout/resources/${project.name}"/>


    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="lib/build" includes="*.zip" />
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${tmp}" />
    </target>

    <target name="init" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${java.classes}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="src" source="1.5" target="1.5" encoding="utf-8" includes="**/*.java" destdir="${java.classes}" classpathref="compile.classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="copy-resources" depends="compile">

            //Lots of copying here

    </target>

    <target name="read.version" description="Parses the hda file for your version number">

        <property file="${project.name}.hda" prefix="hda"/>
        <propertyregex property="version" input="${hda.version}" regexp="\." replace="-" global="true" override="true"/>
        <var name="version2" value="${version}"/>

        <echo>${version}</echo>
        <echo>${version2}</echo>


    </target>

    <target name="zip" depends="copy-resources, read.version" description="Package component">

        <zip destfile="${project.name}-${version}.zip" basedir="${tmp}" />
        <delete dir="${tmp}" />

    </target>


</project>
```

Tarne:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="tarne">

    <include file="build.xml"/>
    <property name="project.name" value="build.project.name"/>

    <target name="tarne">

        <antcall target="build.read.version" inheritRefs="true"></antcall>
        <property name="version" value="build.version"/>
        <property name="version2" value="build.version2"/>

        <echo>${version}</echo> 
        <echo>${version2}</echo>    



    </target>

</project>
```

And the output I get when I run tarne.xml is:

```
Buildfile: tarne.xml
tarne:
build.read.version:
     [echo] v1-0-1
     [echo] v1-0-1
     [echo] default_version_value
     [echo] default_version_value
```

Where the first 2 lines (v1-0-1) are from inside the read.version target of build.xml and the next 2 lines are from tarne.xml. The general idea is that I should be able to access the version number in my tarne.xml build script.

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antcall does not support what you intend to do:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html :
The called target(s) are run in a new project; be aware that this means properties, references, etc. set by called targets will not persist back to the calling project.

you could try:

```
  <target name="tarne" depends="build.read.version">
  </target>
```

which would keep the new values.

Comment: That worked, however Eclipse is screaming at me with the message "Target build.read.version does not exist in this project" (it runs fine, just Eclipse cannot find the target as it's imported). Any ideas on how to get pass that?

Comment: depends ="read.version" should be correct, as you import build.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<property name="version" value="${build.version}"/>         
 <property name="version2" value="${build.version2}"/>
```